# Saving Image from Panel

Tags: c#, winforms, panel

I'm trying to retrieve image drawn on Panel. The image is drawn from SDK for a fingerprint scanner. This is the code I am using to attempt fetching the scanned fingerprint from the panel.

```
int width = Convert.ToInt32(pnlRightThumb.Width);
int height = Convert.ToInt32(pnlRightThumb.Height);
Bitmap left_thumb = new Bitmap(width1, height);
pnlLeftThumb.DrawToBitmap(left_thumb, new Rectangle(0, 0, width1, height1));
left_thumb.Save(Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments), "Fingerprints", "left.bmp"), ImageFormat.Bmp);
```

So far, all I've been able to get is a white image.

*Note: I cannot change the way the image is drawn, I can only attempt to fetch the drawn image from the Panel.*

Comment: Is the SDK code in your application, or are you trying to capture the image from another application ? IMO, the best results will be obtained if you can "hook" into the SDK code and save the image to file directly. Remember that screen resolution will be very low, 72 dpi is typical.

Comment: Yes, that will be ideal. I'll look into the SDK more and find a way with it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key it's the way the image is drawn. If you can't controll it, I thing you have to do a snapshot of your panel,using Graphics object. Try something like this:

```
int width = Convert.ToInt32(pnlRightThumb.Width);
int height = Convert.ToInt32(pnlRightThumb.Height);
Bitmap left_thumb = new Bitmap(width1, height);

Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(left_thumb);
Point panel_location;
panel_location=pnlRightThumb.PointToScreen(Point.Empty);
g.CopyFromScreen(panel_location.X, panel_location.Y, 0, 0, left_thumb.Size, CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);

left_thumb.Save(Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments), "Fingerprints", "left.bmp"), ImageFormat.Bmp);
```

Comment: This solution isn't ideal because, I'll get images like [this](http://i.imgur.com/9VUq5kd.png). There is also the problem of if the user resizes the window.

Comment: Ok, you only have to get the real position of your panel, vía pnlRightThumb.PointToScreen(Point.Empty) method